# Prevent update during paintComponent (Java)

Tags: java, swing, synchronization, locking, paintcomponent

I am having an issue where my `onFrame` method is modifying the position of an object during `paintComponent`. Because my JPanel renders a scene relative to the position of its `focus` object, any shift in the focus position during the painting causes part of the scene to be translated from the rest of the scene (this is visible to the player as a white streak across the screen). Therefore I would like to prevent the `focus` from being modified during part of `paintComponent`.

Here's paint component:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    if (focus == null) {
        return;
    }

    super.paintComponent(g);
    synchronized (focus) {
        universe.getCurrentWorld().render(this, g, true); //draws scene around focus
    }
    focus.getInventory().render(this, g);
    focus.renderHealthBar(g);

    if (dialogQ.peek() != null) {
        dialogQ.peek().render(this, g);
    }

}
```

The render method being called:

```
public void render(FocusedWindow g, Graphics gr, boolean showOutlands) {

    level.renderMap(g, gr, showOutlands);
    col.renderAround(g, gr);

    for (Detector p : colliders.toArray(new Detector[0])) {
        p.renderAround(g, gr);
    }

}
```

The level render method which actually uses `focus`:

```
public void renderMap(FocusedWindow g, Graphics gr, boolean renderOutside) {
    int cushion = 4;
    int scaleFactor = 2;
    int minX = g.getFocus().getPos().getX() / Tile.WIDTH - g.getDimensions().getX() / Tile.WIDTH / scaleFactor - cushion;
    int maxX = g.getFocus().getPos().getX() / Tile.WIDTH + g.getDimensions().getX() / Tile.WIDTH / scaleFactor + cushion;
    int minY = g.getFocus().getPos().getY() / Tile.WIDTH - g.getDimensions().getY() / Tile.WIDTH / scaleFactor - cushion;
    int maxY = g.getFocus().getPos().getY() / Tile.WIDTH + g.getDimensions().getX() / Tile.WIDTH / scaleFactor + cushion;

    for (int i = minX; i < maxX; i++) {
        for (int j = minY; j < maxY; j++) {
            if (i >= 0 && i < map.length) {
                if (j >= 0 && j < map[i].length) {
                    map[i][j].drawTile(g, gr, new Vector(i,j));
                }
                else if (renderOutside) {
                    map[0][0].drawTile(g, gr, new Vector(i,j));
                }
            }
            else if (renderOutside) {
                map[0][0].drawTile(g, gr, new Vector(i,j));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see `focus` being used within your `synchronization` block. I see it being used right under. Move your sync block to those statements

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @VinceEmigh the `universe.getCurrentWorld().render` method takes the focus from the window that is passed (in this case, `this`)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I also need to synchronize the code in `onFrame` which updates the world. After adding two synchronized blocks, it works fine:

```
@Override
protected void onFrame() {

    long time = getTimestamp();
    double deltaTime = (time - lastTime) / 1000000000d;
    lastTime = time;

    if (deltaTime > 0.2) { //this is shitty
        Main.log("high delta time detected (" + deltaTime + " sec)");
    }

    if (dialogQ != null && dialogQ.peek() != null && dialogQ.peek().update(deltaTime)) {
        dialogQ.poll();
    }

    if (isPaused() || isEditingInventory()) {
        return;
    }

    if (!hasDied && focus != null && focus.isDead()) {
        hasDied = true;
        Main.setOverlay(new DeathOverlay());
    }

    if (universe == null || universe.getCurrentWorld() == null) {
        return;
    }

    repaint();
    synchronized (this) {
        universe.getCurrentWorld().update(deltaTime);
    }

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    if (focus == null) {
        return;
    }

    super.paintComponent(g);
    synchronized (this) {
        universe.getCurrentWorld().render(this, g, true);
    }
    focus.getInventory().render(this, g);
    focus.renderHealthBar(g);

    if (dialogQ.peek() != null) {
        dialogQ.peek().render(this, g);
    }

}
```